# Java 1.6 Applet and Mac OS X, is there an official issue here?

Tags: java, macos, applet, compatibility, java-6

I'm developing an applet in Java 1.6 which is supposed (ofcourse) to run on Mac and PC.

However people with Mac seems to all have Java 1.5 installed even due they keep thier software updated with the Mac update tool.

This seems very strange to me that Java isn't automatically updated by Apple as Java 1.6 was released in 2006. Is there an official reason for this?

Also; if I go to http://www.java.com/en/download/help/testvm.xml , Mac OSX isn't listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sun does not release Java for OS X, Apple does that (they have an agreement about it), and it comes out of the box (and with OS updates).

And, in general, Java releases lag significantly behind all other platforms on which Java runs because of it.

Comment: They have 1.6 installed, but it is not the default version. You have to set this in the Java Preferences in the Utility folder.